# How does routing work in javascript MVC frameworks

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

In most of the JavaScript MVC frameworks there is a requirement to separate your application files in to diretories like so:

```
-App
    -Controllers
    -Models
    -Views
```

I'm building my own MVC framework in the hope that it will help me better understand the concepts before I go on to use one of the well established frameworks.

My question is how do the existing frameworks make this directory structure work? How does a controller know that the view is up a directory and in to the views folder for instance? How is this communication made possible?

I've been googling for routing in MVC Javascript. I can see that routing url's specify the controller to be called and parameters to be sent to this controller but this doesn't explain what I need to know.

Comment: Dreamt up a simple way to achieve what I need from reading various resources. These were particularly helpful http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-Where-Does-Node-js-And-Require-Look-For-Modules-.htm http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles

Answer (score 0):

JS MVC frameworks has no directory structure. You can load your MVC components dynamically from directories, but this way is pretty complicated.

Now I have the same problem with a big RIA. I use [Backbone framework](http://backbonejs.org) and I organised directories structure by myself (my structure looks exactly like yours). Then I included all JS files in my HTML template. But  for production mode I merge all my JS files and I put all MVC parts into one file.

At first I tried to load MVC part dynamically from router, but I had a lot problems with loader for  dependencies between models, controllers and views. Also it can slow down your code.

So best way it's  load at once all js files that you need or use [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/).